# Upgraded to 20.04LTS and want the 18.04 "clocks" back

Tags: gnome-clocks

One of the great features of the timer in 18.04LTS was the ability to start and stop using the space bar. The Google Clocks doesn't do this, the Esc function just resets the clock. How do I get back the functionality of the old "Clocks"?